# Generated html code is not click-able

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Help me please i'm a newbie in ajax and framework jQuery , i make in jQuery a page , with different plugins a page , but when i receive html code from ajax  ,and  is not click-able  , i used a function live() , but only helped on plugin delete  , with edit plugin is not working , what can be the problem...

This is script for editing

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.editme').editable('func/update_data.php', {
            submitdata: {
                type: "<?php echo $page_type?>"
            },
            cancel: 'Cancel',
            submit: 'OK',
            tooltip: 'Click to edit...',
            id: 'element_id',
            name: 'update_value',

        });
    });
</script>
```

this is the script  for plugin  modal window and

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#basicModal input.basic, #basicModal a.basic').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#basicModalContent').modal({
            onOpen: function (dialog) {
                dialog.overlay.fadeIn('slow', function () {
                    dialog.data.hide();
                    dialog.container.fadeIn('slow', function () {
                        dialog.data.slideDown('slow');
                    });
                });
            },
            onClose: function (dialog) {
                dialog.data.fadeOut('slow', function () {
                    dialog.container.hide('slow', function () {
                        $.modal.close();
                    });
                });

            }
        });

    });

    $("form#submit_wall").submit(function () {
        var message_wall = $('#message_wall').attr('value');
        $('#message_wall').val('');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "func/insert.php",
            data: "message_wall=" + message_wall,
            dataType: "html",
            complete: function () {
                $('#basicModalContent').html('<div class="succes"><p>Successful</p> Your record was posted  ! </div>');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $.modal.close()
                },
                1200);
            },
            success: function (response) {
                $("div#wall").html(response);
                //$("div#wall").prepend("<span style='display:none'>"+message_wall+"</span>");
                //$("div#wall span").fadeIn();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });

});
```

this is php code for generating html

```
<?php if(isset($_POST[ 'message_wall'])){ 
  /* Remove HTML tag to prevent query injection */ 

  $message=strip_tags($_POST[ 'message_wall']); 
  echo '<div class="container_date">
          <span style="float: left;"> 
            <p class="editme" id="200">Sex</p> 
          </span>
          <span style="float: right;" align="left"> 
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="200" class="delete">Delete</a>  
          </span>
          <br class="clearfloat">
        </div>'; 
} ?>
```

this is first time for posting on this site , sorry for mistakes and for my english

Comment: please fix the post formatting

Comment: Please add proper code tags to make this more legible.

Comment: also it'd be of help if you provided a link to the test page. would help SO supporters debug that and figure out the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very hard to understand what you want, but it looks to me like this:

You are running $('.editme').editable() **only once**, when the document.ready event fires. editable() goes through the DOM at that time, and makes all the elements with class "editme" clickable.

When you add a post and get the response from your PHP script through AJAX, the response contains a P tag with class "editme". But since this happens after document.ready has fired, you will need to run editable() **again** on this new page element to make it clickable.

Answer (score 0):

Big Thanks , i now that is really hard to understand the script , but is my first time to post here , and i have no idea how to ask ,your answer helped me , i put one more time to repeat the editable() inside the php script , response of ajax , and is working !!! ... Big Thanks again !